# What is the difference between an Apple HealthKit query running in the background vs. being enabled for background delivery?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I am reading through the documentation for the Apple HealthKit and am stuck on understanding the difference between a query being registered for background deliveries vs. running on the background. This excerpt from the explanation of anchored object queries seems to differentiate between the two:

> Anchored object query. In addition to returning the current snapshot of modified data, an anchored object query can act as a long-running query. If enabled, it continues to run in the background, providing updates as matching samples are added to or removed from the store. Unlike the observer query, these updates include a list of items that have been added or removed; however, anchored object queries cannot be registered for background delivery.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/reading_data_from_healthkit

I am confused about the difference between the two types of "backgrounds." Does the statement "continues to run in the background" really mean "when the app is in the foreground, this query will continue to run without needing to be re-called?"

Answer (score 0):

Background Delivery works like background app refresh, or GPS significant location change events. It wakes up your app to allow you to act on some event. In this case whenever a health sample you are listening for, is added to the store, your app is woken up (once within a given interval) in order to be able to process the event.

Think of a running/cycling app, where a user is trying to tracking their progress on a long workout. The app won't remain open the whole time, but you can ask for the number of steps every X interval so that you can keep your UI updated, or in sync with a server.

More info on background delivery: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkhealthstore/1614175-enablebackgrounddelivery

The other reference to background, means that it continues to run in another thread, while the app is open. So if you query for heart rate, you can be notified every time a reading comes in, as opposed to just receiving 1 result and having to check every X seconds for a new one